# How to add a condition to a Foreach loop where it will show the newest article using date created on

Tags: c#

Hi I have a foreach loop which lists out all the articles in a service layer, all the articles have a public system namespace DateTime attached to them. I want to edit the foreach loop so i can add a condition to sort the articles descending using the time they where created.

This is what I have at the moment below

```
@foreach (var Article in _Articles)
 {}
```

This is what I want but obviously this doesn't work

```
@foreach (var Article in _Articles.OrderByDescending where _article.CreatedOn )
 {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var Article in _Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedOn))
{
    //Your code here.
}
```

Make sure to import the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Thank you i know its very simple just couldn't work it out

Comment: @Coder175 that's OK. What matters is that you try and keep going. That's what the community is for. 
Don't forget to accept my answer if you found it useful!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Linq

```
@foreach(var Article in _Articles.Where(c => c.CreatedOn >= <<Date Here>>))
{}
```